# Is emotional a negative word?

Tags: word-usage, connotations

I have learned English from TV shows, movies, CNN, Discovery channel, and NGC for years. One of my USA friend told me *emotional* is a negative word such as " Do not be emotional! Yelling and being hysrerical is not helping." and never say " you are emotional" to someone. It sounds refering to being unreasonal rather than emotion and feelings. However, I also googled an possive example, "an emotional support from relatives".  I am confuced by the conflict. Can *emotional* be used in a neutral or positive way such as " Being emotional and rational is equally important to build a successful connection to colleges, which leads to a successful career" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing being **emotional** with **having feelings** or **caring**.
**Emotions** are **feelings**, however **being emotional** is not the same.

In Western parlance, begin **emotional** is the same as being **irrational** the opposite of being **rational**.  Your example of **emotional support** is caring (giving support) for someone who is **struggling emotionally**.

You are also correct in thinking that **feelings** and **empathy** are good qualities to have as a leader. These are usually referred to as

> [**Emotional Intelligence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_intelligence)

but that is **perceiving** emotions not **projecting** emotions (being emotional)

Answer (score 1):

"**Emotional**" has two meanings. The way you mention it means a person **who has or expresses strong feelings**. It is not an insult or a negative thing to say.

> I got very emotional when she gave her speech.

But when you say *"You are being emotional."* or *"Don't be emotional!"*, even though the way you say it changes the meaning, might mean that the person is not acting with his/her intelligence or logic but rather feelings.

> Person A: I can't believe he wanted to watch Super Bowl rather than
>   hang out with me! I will break up with him!
>
> Person B: Come on! You are
>   being emotional.

Also, being emotional is accepted as a weakness -especially for men- in some cultures.

> Dave is more emotional than a little girl. He cried because he is
>   rejected by Mary.

Therefore even though the word itself isn't a bad word or an insult, it might own a meaning that can sound offensive to some people.

Comment: Is it corrent to say that I am emotionslly attached  to the house where I grew up in?

Comment: @Superuser I think to say *sentimentally* attached is better.